# Break one line python code to multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to break one line code into multiple descriptive line because i am unable to understand this one line code.

```
data = formatted_data + "|" + '|'.join(["{}".format(a) for b, a in sorted(values.items()) if a and b not in ['SecureHash']])
```

Is this correct or not any one help me:

```
for b, a in sorted(values.items()):
    if a and b not in ['SecureHash']:
        c = ["{}".format(a)]
        data = formatted_data + "|" + "|".join(c)
```

Comment: line breaks between `()` are legal so you can hit Enter after the first `join(` for example

Comment: your code seems to be correct only thing that if you want to use c as a list you can use it as `c = [a]` or remove c assignment change data to `data = formatted_data + "|" + "|".join([a])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, generally you can see any opening bracket and the plus operators in the string as a "breaking point". Working with your example:

```
data = formatted_data
data += "|"
data += '|'.join(["{}".format(a) for b, a in sorted(values.items()) if a and b 
not in ['SecureHash']])
```

OK so now we need to unpack what's happening in that join:

```
data = formatted_data
data += "|"
jointmp = ["{}".format(a) for b, a in sorted(values.items()) if a and b not in ['SecureHash']]
data += '|'.join(jointmp)
```

OK so we've got some string formatting and a bunch of list comprehensions:

```
data = formatted_data
data += "|"

jointmp = []
for b, a in sorted(values.items()):
  if a and b not in ['SecureHash']:
      jointmp += ["{}".format(a)] # Equivalent to str(a) ?

data += '|'.join(jointmp)
```

To do the last stage there was a lot of going back and for as things were expanded. Those list comprehensions are quite terse...

There are some questions here though:

- Where did `values` come from?
- What's the `"{}".format(a)` for?

etc.

Your "expanded" code is not quite equivalent because you don't handle the case where there are no matches / `values` is empty and you are replacing `data` each time rather than growing it.

Answer (score 2):

This code is collecting a string representation of `a`, and then building another string with it.

You need to define an external list, to account for the list comprehension expression.

```
c = ["{}".format(a) for b, a in sorted(values.items()) if a and b not in ['SecureHash']]
```

Further, to break down how `c` is being assembled, you can expand the list comprehension:

```
c = []
for b, a in sorted(values.items()):
    if a and b not in ['SecureHash']:
        c.append('{}'.format(a))
```

Finally, just combine the three parts:

```
data = formatted_data + "|" + "|".join(c)
```

Comment: Thanks @Burhan Khalid.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to read up on [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

basically it's making a list of things like this:
`[item for item in iterable_thing]`

so this one is making a list of strings (`"{}".format(a)`). I assume `a` is a hash, but let's pretend it's a number in a range:
`["{}".format(a) for a in range(5)]`
will make:
`>>>['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']`

Comprehensions can become quite complicated with the addition of `if` statements, and whoever wrote this code is one of those `a in b in i in j` kind of people, it seems, so their code is hard to follow. Good variable names are SO important.

Comment: Also, the function is making a list first using that comprehension, and then joining the items in the list together with pipe characters `|` -- so this line:  
`"|" + "|".join( [ "{}".format(a) for a in range(5) ] )`  
will output:  
`>>>"|0|1|2|3|4"`